# PhalconPHP - CSS not working

Tags: php, html, css, phalcon

so I've started dealing with PhalconPHP and I was going through some examples and I couldn't get the CSS working. So I downloaded this INVO sample application (https://github.com/phalcon/invo), put in the htdocs folder, loaded it in the browser and it is also missing the css, just blank text on a white screen. So there must be something wrong with my installation, any ideas what that might be?

Thanks!

Comment: Check CSS File Path or inspect your page in browser

Comment: Also delete the cached pages, Phalcon caches pages :)

Answer (score 3):

Try clearing the baseUri value in app/config/config.ini from:

```
baseUri        = /invo/
```

to

```
baseUri        = /
```

I had an issue that looked the same as yours, then i noticed all links in the application are prefixed with "invo" as if my application would be in an "invo" subfolder, but it wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

For the described situation I would say that your issue is similar to this question: 
[Image resources with Phalcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261546/image-resources-with-phalcon/24265903#24265903).

But since you have downloaded the INVO tutorial and it isn't working either I'd that's something to do within your Apache configuration. Please lead to this question: [Friendly URLs in phalcon framwork is not working in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049941/friendly-urls-in-phalcon-framwork-is-not-working-in-ubuntu/24050475#24050475)

If none of these solutions solve your problems please let me know and provide more info.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have enabled mod_rewrite but nothing happened. I just tryied clicking some of the links and it gives a 404 - Object not found. Seems that there's some major error in my Phalcon. However when I write "phalcon commands" in the cmd it shows them so no idea what might be the problem. Also it shows on 'localhost' -> phpinfo and it is enabled.

Comment: @user43051 the second solution I've proposed isn't about `mod_rewrite` have you read about the `AllowOverride` setting? Have you checked it?

Comment: Yes, I changed all 'AllowOverride's to ALL. This is what I get for the directory:

<Directory "E:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Should there be something for htdocs where the project is in? I tried adding an entry for it but then it shows in the browser that I don't have permissions to access it.

Comment: I forgot to mention this is the httpd.conf in E:\xampp\apache\conf ... should I change any other one?

Comment: @user43051 the `AllowOverride` you've found is for the **cgi-bin** folder. Modify or create one `<Directory>` section for your **htdocs**.

Comment: Thanks but do you have any idea what should I put between the directory tags? I tried the same as above but it shows Access forbidden. Then I tried: Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
(saw it somewhere online) and it shows the page as before - no css and links not working.

Comment: @user43051 `<Directory "xx/yy">` means "the following rules applies only for the folder xx/yy". Try to restore your Apache configurations then just add the `AllowOverride` setting and finally check if the Phalcon **.htaccess** files are OK ([**more info here**](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/apache.html)).

Comment: I think I got them all right but it still doesn't work. Are you able to run the Invo? If so can you tell me what is it in your httpd.conf file? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55797/discussion-between-cvsguimaraes-and-user43051).